# c# sound recognition in video editor

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, video-editing, mediainfo

I'm currently coding a specialised video editor.
It's specialised because it is used by lecturers in my sch to record e-learning lectures.
It uses **C#**, **WPF** and **Microsoft Expression Encoder**.
The basic functions like cut and insert video are already done.
Now i'm trying to figure out a way for sound recognition.
How it works:

1. The user selects a part of the video
2. The video editor takes note of the sound during that part
3. The video editor searches the rest of the video for similar sounds
4. The video editor highlights those parts of the video and gives the user a chance to edit them.

The videos are in xesc format.
Could anyone direct me to any library/tutorial that can help achieve that?
Sorry I'm new to sound analysis and editing.

Libraries found so far:
Naudio & Mediainfo.dll
However, these libraries dont support xesc.
Should I convert these videos to mp4 beforehand for easier sound analysis?
Is there any algorithm to detect similar sound samples?

Sorry for the trouble!
Thanks!